# React/React Native onLayout for Child View

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am looking to build a button/view that animates when a user taps and holds on it. This animation will just be a progressive change of color from white to a green color. I have found a tutorial that does exactly this:

http://browniefed.com/blog/react-native-press-and-hold-button-actions/

In the render function, the author uses:

```
<View style={styles.container} onLayout={this.onPageLayout}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
            onPressIn={this.handlePressIn}
            onPressOut={this.handlePressOut}
        >
            <View style={styles.button} onLayout={this.onPageLayout2}>
              <Animated.View style={[styles.bgFill, this.getProgressStyles()]} />
              <Text style={styles.text}>Press And Hold Me</Text>
            </View>
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        <View>
            <Text>{this.state.textComplete}</Text>
        </View>
   </View>
```

**Please note there are two onLayout mentions...one in the parent View and the other in the View about halfway down**

The way this works is the onLayout call is supposed to get the size of the TouchableWithoutFeedback button so that I can set the animation to have the correct sizing. However, the second onLayout call just does not get called no matter what I try. The very top View's onLayout is being called so I know that my code is good (as this.onPageLayout and this.onPageLayout2 are exact copies except their console.logs vary slightly).

If I remove all the surrounding code and only have the inner View in this render function, then the onLayout={this.onPageLayout2} works like a charm, but as soon as I put the rest of the parent back in, it no longer works.

Does anybody know how I can get a child View to have their onLayout method work? Or another way or getting the size of the TouchableWithoutFeedback button for my purposes of animation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `TouchableWithoutFeedback` and so you don't get any feedback from it's child. Change it to other buttons for example: `TouchableOpacity`, Then you can have `onLayout` for both components.

Comment: I can give that a try tmrw...but if you wouldn't mind seeing my second to last paragraph in my question, I  was able to get it to work with TouchableWithoutFeedback as long as it wasn't a child. Any other thoughts? I'll let you know my results tomorrow

Comment: I'ts not about `TouchableWithoutFeedback` bing a child, it's about `TouchableWithoutFeedback` having a child :). You just can't get feedback from TouchableWithoutFeedback's child.

Comment: Ok...it was an issue with TouchableWithoutFeedback...why can you not get the size of a child here though? I don't quite understand the difference between that, and say, TouchableOpacity?

Comment: I can't test it right now, can you add another `View` wrapper around `View` with `onLayout={this.onPageLayout2}` property? test it with `TouchableWithoutFeedback`.

Comment: It didn't work that way either...but having just the TouchableWithoutFeedback without any views around it does work...strange

Comment: I think it's a react native bug. adding a parent `View` shouldn't have any effect to it's child.